# Upload and Download with one page

Tags: html, asp-classic, upload, download

I created asp form which supported download and upload functionality. see below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function clickUpload() {
                document.getElementById("UploadFile").click();
            }

            function clickDownload() {
                document.getElementById("DownloadForm").submit();
            }

            function MakeUpload() {
                document.getElementById("UploadForm").submit();
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="Test1.asp">
            <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="clickUpload();" />
            <input type="button" value="Download" onclick="clickDownload();" />
            <form id="UploadForm" action="test3.asp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" id="UploadFile" onchange="MakeUpload();" style="display:none" />
            </form>
            <form id="DownloadForm" action="Test4.asp">
            </form>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the moment, the upload doesn't work. How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting the script on the bottom of your code, just before the < / body > tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest FORM tags. If you remove the outer FORM tag it should work. But did you need the FORM that submits to "Test1.asp"?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function clickUpload() {
                document.getElementById("UploadFile").click();
            }

            function clickDownload() {
                document.getElementById("DownloadForm").submit();
            }

            function MakeUpload() {
                document.getElementById("UploadForm").submit();
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="clickUpload();" />
            <input type="button" value="Download" onclick="clickDownload();" />
            <form id="UploadForm" action="test3.asp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" id="UploadFile" onchange="MakeUpload();" style="display:none" />
            </form>
            <form id="DownloadForm" action="Test4.asp">
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is with the main form that encloses the other two form. you have to close it as java script is not able to find the upload form